# Google docs viewer returning blank screen (204 response) sometimes

Tags: google-document-viewer, http-status-code-204

We use Google doc viewer to view pdf files which sometimes responds back with 204 - an untitled document. After a page refresh the content gets loaded. We have tried to add embed tags which doesn’t solve the issue. 
We have also noticed that the https security is missing when we receive this 204 untitled response.
We have also found few threads in the Google forum with the same issue but we didn’t get any resolution captured.

Our code is like below

```
<a href="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=www.example.com/abc.pdf" target="_blank" title="Opens preview in new window">
                            ABC
                        </a>
```

Is there any alternative to it? We have tried 'office viewer' but we had issues with that too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same issue , can you found any solution ?

Comment: No we are still facing the same issue. Guess it is a known issue with Google Docs Viewer.